# Converting String to Generics type argument in Java

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I would like to write a Generic program that receives a String from the user and creates a container of that type using reflection. This should be something on the lines of

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the type you want to use ");
    String typeName = scanner.nextLine();
    Set<????> mySet = new HashSet(); 
}
```

What should I put in the ???? part? Is this possible?

Comment: "What should I put in the ???? part?" What do you want to do with `mySet`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java generics type erasure: when and what happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Comment: In short, something like `Set<String>` becomes just `Set` at runtime.  The type argument is only syntax sugar.  It's just something that the compiler looks at and stops you from doing stupid things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure, what you try to achieve. I assume, the code will go on after you've created that `Set` of `typeName`.
About generics. After the code is compiled, all information about generics is gone. During runtime, when you've created the type of `typeName`, for the program, it's just gonna be an Object.
Generics is just so that while programming, it's clear, which type of `Object` you are handling with, so that you don't need to cast and the compiler can check that this generally works.
If you want to call something on the object later, you'll need to use reflection unless you made some more precise information, which kind of `Object` you're dealing with.

The easiest thing to put there is just `Object`.